# Testing GUIs with GoogleTest & QTest

Tags: c++, qt, googletest, privacy, qtest

I have a GUI and I want to test the many functionalities of this GUI.  The issue is that the sub-widgets are all private members of this main GUI class.  How can I test my main GUI when I can't populate any of these sub-widgets since they are private to me in the test class?

For example, I have multiple line edits as fields in the `ui` object.  These line edits are scraped and dumped into a QVariant object type specific to this GUI.  I can't populate these edits from my test functions since they are inaccessible due to privacy issues.  Therefore, I can't test the QVariant object matches the data supplied by the GUI.

I also can not call any of the QTest functions on specific widgets to trigger events.

For example, I can't call

`QTest::mouseClick(testGUI.ui->pushButton1, ...)`

because `ui` is private and `pushButton1` would be private whether it was part of the UI or not.  Therefore, I can't simulate mouse click events on these buttons either.  I also tried to use

`QTest::mouseClick(testGUI, ..., ..., ..., QPoint(70, 180));`

Where the QPoint is the absolute position of the button with respect to the widget, but even this doesn't trigger the button clicked.

How can I test these widgets when so much of the widget is private and inaccessible to the user?

Comment: GUI is not good subject for unit-testing. It is really important to see how it looks - UT will not replace your eyes. But - you should extract/separate all business logic from your GUI and unit-test this business logic code.

Comment: I use friend declaration to grant test code access to protected and private members of code under test. For GoogleTest there is a macro FRIEND_TEST to declare test functions as friend. Maybe not the most elegant method but works for me for simple test scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create shared library which includes the directory build-xxx-desktop-debug.
Then in the test.pro you do the libs.

Hope it works.